# ng-if initial animation not working with a custom directive

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, ng-animate

if ng-if and a custom directive are put together on the same DOM element, the initial animation does not work.

```
<div ng-if="value" myDirective class="fadeMe"></div>
```

Here is a [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/XYZdNxwAtd6dF2sw3D95?p=preview) and clearly shows the problem. Notice that only the initial show fade fails.

**More Details**:
I am guessing it has something to do with the priority of both directives (ngif is compiled first).

I tried to set a higher priority to the custom directive but I ran into more issues such as the child scope of the custom directive does not get destroyed by ng-if, therefore, unnecessary watchers in the custom directive keep watching values.

Comment: can you put the ng-if and class to the root of the directive template? http://plnkr.co/edit/zEuiEKpsk2AHGigSgXcq?p=preview

Comment: I can, however, with this approach in a very complex application, I will have many custom directives floating around and will increase the DOM. I wanted all of these custom directives to be removed from the DOM and shown when needed. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to be related to this issue:

https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/14074

If you use inline template instead of templateURL in your directive it starts working.

Comment: Very useful link. Seems that the animation starts before the templateURL is loaded for the 1st time as it is not cached.
https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/14074#issuecomment-185938924

Answer (score 1):

It looks like there is a timing issues in data binding in Angular directive "restrict type" of class.

`restrict: 'C'`

So a as fast fix use

`restrict: 'A'`

http://plnkr.co/edit/2iB9jvpGSMi3IwelicXT

Comment: Hi Khaled, your plunker shows the directive name (al-login) is applied as class instead of attribute although you defined restrict: 'A'. Shouldn't it be an attribute? the problem occurs again when you use it as an attribute.

Comment: Agreed! As I mentioned looks like it is a bug in angular, you should open an issue on github for that